# VHDL: Can a signal be used as an index for an aggregate?

Tags: vhdl

Is it legal to use an integer signal in place of an integer literal as an index in a named association? I want to do so in order to create a decoder, like this:

```
reg_clk_en <= (write_reg => '1', others => '0');
```

where `reg_clk_en` is a `std_logic_vector` and `write_reg` is an `integer` (with range 0 to 31).

From what I have read on Renerta about [Aggregates](http://vhdl.renerta.com/mobile/source/vhd00002.htm) and [Expressions](http://vhdl.renerta.com/mobile/source/vhd00029.htm), I think this should be legal: `write_reg` is a legal *choices* clause because it is a *name*, which is a *simple expression*. However I'm not sure I understand this quote:

> A value of simple expression can be applied in arrays only and must belong to discrete range of an array type. A simple expression specifies the element at the corresponding index value.

The first sentence seems to say that it's OK to use an integer index as long as the target of the aggregate assignment is an array, and the value of the integer is within the range of the array type. The second sentence seems to confirm that the expression `array(index)` refers to the element of `array` at `index` - but this is so blatantly obvious that I suspect I am misreading it.

The reason I am asking is that Vivado rejects my initial code snippet with the following message:

`[Synth 8-211] could not evaluate expression: aggregate choice expression`

I know of other ways to specify a decoder, but none so concise. Most importantly, I would like to understand **why** that code snippet is problematic for Vivado. If it isn't legal VHDL, what about it is incorrect?

Answer (score 3):

You're conflating legal syntax and semantics.

Your aggregate uses element association.

What element of `reg_clk_en` has the name `write_reg`?

See IEEE Std 1076-2008 9.3.3 Aggregates, note choices simple_expression and *element*_simple_name in the BNF, paragraph:

```
element_association ::=  
    [ choices => ] expression  

choices ::= choice { | choice }  

choice ::= 
      simple_expression
    | discrete_range
    | element_simple_name
    | others
```

There's a requirement that an index in an aggregate be locally static (determined at analysis time), which prevents you from using a signal value.  That requirement is found in 9.3.3.3 Array aggregates, paragraph 7:

> Apart from a final element association with the single choice others, the rest (if any) of the element associations of an array aggregate shall be either all positional or all named. ***A named association of an array aggregate is allowed to have a choice that is not locally static, or likewise a choice that is a null range, only if the aggregate includes a single element association and this element association has a single choice***. An others choice is locally static if the applicable index constraint is locally static.

If you follow the BNF from simple_expression through primary:

```
simple_expression ::=
     [ sign ] term { adding_operator term }

term ::=
     factor { multiplying_operator factor }

factor ::=
     primary [ ** primary ]
   | abs primary
   | not primary
   | logical_operator primary

primary ::= 
     name 
   | literal
   | aggregate
   | function_call
   | qualified_expression 
   | type_conversion
   | allocator
   | ( expression )
```

we find your name. You can look through 9.4.2 Locally static primaries and determine signals aren't mentioned, while a constant is (9.4.2 b).

So we see that your aggregate is not eligible to be taken as the value provided by the evaluation of the simple expression that is a signal name. If declared as a constant it would be:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity foo is
end entity;

architecture fum of foo is
    signal reg_clk_en: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    constant write_reg: natural := 3;
begin
    reg_clk_en <= (write_reg => '1', others => '0');
end architecture;
```

This analyzes, elaborates and simulates (while doing nothing particularly interesting).

The only other possible evaluation of the name as an index would be as an element name of a record, noting your code snippet isn't a minimal, complete and verifiable example (lacking declarations).

9.3.3 Aggregates, 9.3.3.1 General, paragraph 5:

> An element association with a choice that is an element simple name is only allowed in a record aggregate. An element association with a choice that is a simple expression or a discrete range is only allowed in an array aggregate: a simple expression specifies the element at the corresponding index value, whereas a discrete range specifies the elements at each of the index values in the range. ...

Assuming it's an array type the standard tells us a signal can't be used as an index for an aggregate in the manner you have attempted.

Non-authoritative resources can't always be relied on to fully define acceptable semantics.

Comment: Why is the constant a simple_expression and the signal a simple_name? From 1.3.2.{g,h}, it seems both could be a simple_name, because each is "an identifier that already denotes some declared entity". Under 8.1, a simple_name is a name, so under 9.1 a simple_expression could be just a simple_name. So it seems that both the constant and the signal could be a simple_name or a simple_expression (or both), which is problematic for reading paragraph 5. How do you resolve this?

Comment: "How do you resolve this?" wanders into implementation detail. Both BNF productions can produce the same [abstract syntax tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) for your example where subsequent and separate semantic analysis can determine the meaning based on descriptive attributes of declared entities (6.1) knowing it's an aggregate expression. Production rule test order for choice can be arbitrary, the first one satisfied is acceptable. Concrete syntax trees describing productions aren't needed.

Comment: @user8352 can we write something like this reg_clk_en <= (write_reg => '1'); where write_reg is integer port

Answer (score 1):

Important thing to note is that VHDL statements inside a process are applied sequentially to create the result.  This isn't the same as sequential execution; what it means is that later assignments completely replace earlier ones (reconnect the circuitry, unlike concurrent statements where multiple drivers need resolution as wired-OR / wired-AND).  In your case, you can write:

```
PROCESS (write_reg)
BEGIN
    reg_clk_en <= (others => '0'); -- all elements become '0' ...
    reg_clk_en(write_reg) <= '1';  --                         ... except write_reg
END PROCESS;
```

which has the intended semantics and works properly when `write_reg` is NOT a `constant` or `generic`.

Of course, this will fail when `write_reg` is outside of `reg_clk_en'RANGE`.  In simulation you'll get an error, while in synthesis you'll get unpredictable results (maybe the synthesizer determined that it could ignore upper bits, for example, and you end up with a modulo decoder).

Comment: While this is true (if by 'VHDL statements' you exclusively mean signal assignment), it doesn't really answer the question, which wasn't 'how can I make this code work' but 'is this legal, and why or why not?'. Still, it may be useful to others who find this question when looking for help implementing a decoder...

Comment: @odougs: It is signal assignments that get combined in this fashion (and variable assignments -- the significant difference is when the right-hand side of the variable assignment refers to the same variable), but other statements such as conditionals take part in this process.

Comment: @ Ben Voigt: When is that true for variable assignments? I thought the only exception to the 'sequential execution' model is that signal assignment schedules an update on the signal, which takes effect some time after the process is done, and uses the last (or only) value assigned to the signal. Is there any other way in which statements within a process body (not the activation of the process itself) differ in control flow / execution model from a software language like C or Java?

Comment: @odougs: You're thinking of simulation, I'm thinking of hardware synthesis.  In software, or VHDL simulation, each variable assignment takes an execution cycle.  In hardware, each variable assignment creates an logic node which can feed into other logic on the same variable, but it all happens during a single clock cycle.  And later writing the variable with a constant can cause all the earlier circuitry to totally disappear.  (Actually, an optimizing simulator might also remove intermediate assignments)

Answer (score -1):

```
reg_clk_en <= (write_reg => '1', others => '0');
```

The first error i see is,you have declared write_reg to be of integer type & you are assigning it '1' which is a bit type.

and why do you want to use aggregates if want to do what you're trying.

Suppose reg_clk_en is std_logic_vector(9 downto 0)

then you can just do:

```
reg_clk_en(9 downto 4) <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(write_reg,6));
reg_clk_en(3 downto 0) <= (OTHERS => '0');
```

Comment: This doesn't implement a demux, as specified in the question.